# Why should a python variable of type list should be defined first before assigning a value?

Tags: python

`x = 2`

creates an integer variable.

`y.append(3)`

gives an error message (name 'y' is not defined).

In the first one a variable `x` can be assigned a value without first defining it, why can't we do the same thing with the lists (you have to first define it using `l = []`). Is this the result of a fundamental design choice in the Python language?
Thanks.

Comment: If I would have asked you to "add 3 to the list" you would say "what list?", wouldn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual act of assignment also creates the variable if it doesn't exist.

When you attempt to call a member function the variable needs to exist, so the Python interpreter knows what kind of variable it is (the type of the variable). If the interpreter doesn't know the kind of the variable, it can't know what member functions exist on the object.

Comment: I thought that the interpreter could have created a list since append() is used but this assumes that append() is a unique member function name which is an implausible assumption. Thanks for your answer.